# Detecting concurrency issues in Entity Framework using transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency

I have save code that I'm using to help minimize concurrency issues. It is structured similar to this:

```
// HasConcurrencyIssues opens a new EntityContext and gets the actual current
// details and then compares it to what was loaded for the form
if (this.HasConcurrencyIssues()) {

    // can't save, exit out of save code
    return;
}

using (EntityContext context = new EntityContext()) {

    // shared locks to avoid dirty reads - should I be using this?       
    IsolationLevel level = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;

    using (DbContextTransaction trans == context.Database.BeginTransaction(level)) {

        try {

            // here is where I save stuff using the context by adding
            // items to the DbSets
            this.SaveStuff(context);

            // execute the generated SQL commands before secondary check because
            // this could take some time
            context.SaveChanges();

            // check again in case something happened after executing SaveChanges()
            // ** gets blocked here **
            if (this.HasConcurrencyIssues()) {

                // can't save, rollback and exit out of save code
                trans.Rollback();
                return;
            }

            trans.Commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            // handle error
            trans.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

I was using this structure to help minimize concurrency issues. The problem I'm having is that I'm not really understanding how `ReadCommitted` and concurrency work together. I've noticed that on my second check for concurrency issues it gets blocked because it isn't able to read the current records (I'm assuming this has to do with my chosen `IsolationLevel`). I'm worried that if I remove that secondary check it could lead to phantom data that I don't want.

The application is being scaled up and needs to be able to handle ~200 users that could potentially want to edit the same object and save it. I basically want a hard stop that checks if the object has changed and if it has, prevent a save.

How can I structure my save code to minimize concurrency issues?

**Edit**

I realize that it's being locked because the check is after the `SaveChanges` call. If I place the secondary check before the `SaveChanges` call it would work, but isn't it possible that a transaction could finish while it is saving which should cause a concurrency issue to show up, but won't?

---

Relevant system architecture:

- `Entity Framework 6`
- `SQL Server 2012`

Comment: It seems like detecting and preventing concurrency issues is usually best left to the database and its handling of transactions. Can you explain what sort of concurrency issues you're trying to avoid, and why you can't just use a simple `TransactionScope` with its default isolation level?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Let's assume `User A` and `User B` both open a form that edits `Object A`. If `User B` saves and closes the form, `User A`'s form is now invalid. I need to be able to prevent `User A` from saving because they would write records that are technically not correct.

Comment: That's a common problem usually dealt with by *optimistic concurrency*. EF fully supports this concurrency strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be a simpler approach:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope())
{
    if (this.HasConcurrencyIssues()) {
        // can't save, exit out of save code
        return;
    }

    using (EntityContext context = new EntityContext()) {
        this.SaveStuff(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    ts.Complete();
}
```

Because your transaction scope has already begun when you read the information from the database, no other thread is going to be allowed to change that information until you've finished saving.

Likewise, if another thread has already read information to determine if there are any concurrency issues, your call to HasConcurrencyIssues() won't return until they've finished saving their changes.

The transaction scope will automatically roll back at the end of the `using` block if it hasn't completed, so there's no need for additional try/catch logic.

Comment: This is using distributed transactions which are not advisable or available in many system designs.

Comment: @usr: Is there any reason to think that this wouldn't work for the OP's situation? There are certainly safer/better approaches out there, but all the ones I can think of are quite a bit more complicated. If this works, I'd go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Working with two transactions on the same data is asking for trouble. You'll get all kinds of blocking behavior, often dependent on the query plan. During testing this might work and later break under load. You'll create distributed deadlocks (involving multiple connections). SQL Server has no way of breaking them. You'll basically lock some data and hold up execution for the duration of the 30s timeout. A scalability killer.

Use a single context, connection and transaction. Get your locking right.

Either understand locking in SQL Server better and apply the right isolation level and maybe pessimistic locking hints. Or, use a solution that always works: `SERIALIZABLE`. This isolation level guarantees results as-if only one transaction was running at the same time. Treat deadlocks by retrying the transaction.

`SERIALIZABLE` tends to cause more blocking and deadlocking. Depending on the workload this might not be an issue at all, or deadly.

Investigate `SNAPSHOT` isolation for readers. It removes all locking on data and results in perfect data consistency.

This is really all the advice I can give without information about the concrete queries and locks involved.

Comment: Essentially, I will update two tables by end effectiving their records, and then I will insert the new records. So `SaveChanges` is going to call a bunch of UPDATE and INSERT statements. Does that info help for elaboration? You've worried me such that I don't think I'm handling this right.

Comment: Making the changes atomic is very easy by using a transaction. Making other transactions be isolated from those changes is harder. What concrete scenario are you worried about? Example: Let's say two trans try to read an int, increment it and write it back. It is important that the read be part of the transaction (do you understand why?). Are your reads (that the writes are computed from) part of the transaction? Doesn't look like it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify isolation level as ReadCommitted unless you don't change it in your sql server by means of SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL command or anywhere else in the application. Because ReadCommitted is the default setting in sql server.

It would be useful to review [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) and [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378149(v=sql.110).aspx) to understand for possible scenarios.